# Создать несколько процессов

Tags: c#, процесс

Задача состоит в том, что есть у меня процесс который табулирует функцию, сделать обчисление данной функции в 2х,4х,8х процессах, подскажите как реализовать данные условия.

Comment: Процессах или всё же потоках?

Comment: Если процесс не умеет "обчисливать" функцию на некотором интервале, а умеет только целиком - никак. И каким это боком относится к проблеме создания нескольких процессов - совершенно не ясно.

Comment: ArchDemonn, процесс

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку то, о чём вы спрашиваете, похоже на учебное задание, я не буду давать конкретный код, а дам просто общие намётки того, как я бы это делал.

Самый простой вариант — разделение работы в самом начале, при котором задача «протабулировать функцию» делится на 2 (или 4, или 8) подзадач. Вы запускаете управляющий процесс, который делит задание на части, запускает рабочие процессы, и собирает у них результат.

Например, если вам нужно протабулировать функцию на отрезке [*a*, *b*], вы можете поделить отрезок на 8 частей, и каждая часть будет представлять отдельную подзадачу табуляции. После этого вы запускаете 8 копий рабочего процесса, передавая им каждому свою подзадачу как входной параметр (например, через командную строку).

Вам нужно будет ещё подумать о сборе результатов. Например, если все процессы пишут в выходные файлы (путь к которым тоже бы неплохо передать на вход), в конце вам нужно будет собрать все результаты в один выходной файл.

Более сложный вариант — общение процессов через ту или иную разновидность IPC. Например, рабочие 8 процессов могут писать не в файл, а в выходной поток, ваш управляющий процесс должен будет перенаправить потоки ввода-вывода рабочих процессов, и собирать результат из них.

Ещё более продвинутый вариант — динамическое распределение нагрузки между рабочими процессами. Для этого вам нужна будет двусторонняя коммуникация с рабочими процессами. Вы запускаете ваши рабочие процессы, и выдаёте им задание на табуляцию маленькой части исходного отрезка. Тот процесс, который первым закончит, получает следующее задание. Таким образом, ни один рабочий процесс не будет простаивать.

Comment: Можно ссылку на полезную документацию как эти действия реализовать?

Comment: @KolyaOlya: Ну, нету документации, которая говорит, как реализовать подобную систему. То есть есть, это https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/, документация по всей системе. Документация говорит о конкретных вещах, наподобие того, как создать процесс и как передать ему аргументы.